# MIME content-transfer-encoding type "Hexa"

Tags: mime-types

I recently ran across a piece of spam-mail where most of the attachments had a `content-transfer-encoding` of `Hexa`.

What is this?  Or what is it supposed to be?

The content of these attachments appears to actually be `Base64` encoded.

After quite a bit of web searching, I can't find any documentation about this encoding.  I'd ordinarily just assume that it's bogus, but GMail seemed to have no problem decoding it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr: "Hexa" is an invalid Content-Transfer-Encoding value. Your spammer is sending broken emails.**

There are only five valid values for the Content-Transfer-Encoding header: "7bit", "8bit", "base64", "quoted-printable" and "binary". (Private implementations can use other values with an "X-" prefix but obviously no other implementation will recognise these.)

This was originally specified way back in 1992 in [RFC 1341](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/5_Content-Transfer-Encoding.html), but it hasn't changed since then. As that RFC points out:

> The definition of new content-transfer-encodings is explicitly discouraged

So you'll find the same five values described in modern documentation of the header, e.g. [IBM's](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ste/8.4.1?topic=fields-content-transfer-encoding-header-field).